# How to prevent exposure of methods and header files(.h) of other library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I’m creating one framework, which is using another third party static framework (has .h file, which contains public methods) and I don’t want to expose the header files(.h), code, methods and classes of that library to the user of my library.

Any ideas will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to hide ALL header files, or just that of the 3rd party library?

Comment: It would be fine to hide the third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to control header file visibility in `Build Phases`

[image: 555]